# Flutter Slidable Text Overflows the Border

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_slidable package and I want to implement slidable text, when trying to slide the text overflows the container's border.

How can I implement it so that, the text doesn't overflows the borders?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
            ),
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: Slidable(
              // The start action pane is the one at the left or the top side.
              startActionPane: ActionPane(
                // A motion is a widget used to control how the pane animates.
                motion: const ScrollMotion(),

                // All actions are defined in the children parameter.
                children: [
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: (context) {},
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF21B7CA),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.share,
                    label: 'Share',
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              // The end action pane is the one at the right or the bottom side.
              endActionPane: ActionPane(
                motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                children: [
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: (context) {},
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0392CF),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.save,
                    label: 'Save',
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              // The child of the Slidable is what the user sees when the
              // component is not dragged.
              child: const ListTile(title: Text('Slide me')),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screen Shot of Overflowing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `clipBehavior` of the container is `Clip.none`. You can provide other than none.

```dart
child: Container(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, // this
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(),
  ),
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  child: Slidable(
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)